# High CPU load on server with no processes running

Tags: server, java, cpu, process

I'm working on one of my university's servers, where I've been given space on the server and allocated 40 cores.

Currently, according to top, I have no processes running except the root processes. The only process that is taking up CPU power is x11vnc, and no processes are taking up MEM. Despite this, the load averages are 46.08, 46.03, 46.05.

I think what might have happened is that I was running a java process in a screen with multithreading, so all 40 cores were in use, but instead of killing the process itself I just killed the screen, which may have prevented the java process from exiting properly.

I thought if I tried killing all processes with a command like `shutdown -h now` or `killall5 -9` it might solve the problem but I'm hesitant to try for fear of killing important root processes and generally making things worse.

Any ideas for troubleshooting/fixing the issue would be welcome.

EDIT: The server has htop installed, but attempting to run htop gives me a completely blank window that I can't exit with `q` or `Ctrl+C`, I have to close the window instead. Not sure if this is a related issue or not.

Comment: do you have root priviledge?

Comment: Yes I have root @Katu

Comment: Try running `top` or `ps aux` with root priviledge. You should see all the processes and you will be able to see who is using the CPU. You can also install `htop` which presents the information in a nicer way.

Comment: Just tried running top as root. There's no difference than there was before. I'm pretty sure there isn't an actual process running with a cpu load of ~40, as I can still run other jobs.

Comment: Why don't you want to run `shutdown -h now`? It just reboots the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running `shutdown -h now`, and CPU load is back to 0.08, 0.09, 0.05, so that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

CPU power may not only be used by user processes but also be the kernel itself.

If you write that "you have been given space" on that server, what exactly does that mean?

Try running finger and find out if any other users are using the server at the same time. If that's the case (i.e. it's a shared resource) and they have given you root, it sounds scary to me.

So in other words: If you're alone on the box, the non-scientific way of just rebooting should solve your problem, though you will not find out that way what the problem actually was.

Comment: So when I say server, in this case the university's high-performance computing department runs a cluster, of which our lab has 7TB of storage. Within this 7TB I have root access but cannot access any other part of the cluster, so rest assured that they haven't given me admin privileges to the entire university-wide setup.

Comment: Haven't tried finger yet, but running top shows that my 'part' of the server has 2 users, which would not be the case if top was listing the number of users accessing the entire cluster.